# Converting a Number in a string to a Currency format

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my ASP.net C# application, I have to retrieve values from different databases and stored them in string variables.

One of the variables is used to store Product Amount(pd_amnt) from Italy. So there the values are in the form of "1.000.000.000,00" but I need to replace all the (.) to (,) then the values are in the form of "1,000,000,000.00". To solve this issue I used Replace(), but it failed because nobody can expect how many commas (,) will come for a particular string value.

How to solve this issue? Is there any separate method for the same in C# .NET?

```
 protected void btnSub_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                //Try1
        double value = 1.234567890;

        Response.Write(value.ToString("#,#", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        Response.Write(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,"{0:#,#}", value));

                     //Try2
        string a = txtvalue.Text;

        string b= a.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-US"));
        txtConverted.Text = b.ToString();

    }
```

Comment: The solution would be if you have a string of a number from italian in their format then use their `CultureInfo` to parse it into a number. This would take account the format in terms of thousand separators, decimal separators and anything else that might be different. Also why do you need to know the number of commas to use replace?

Comment: Just use the overload of `double.ToString`(or `decimal.ToString`) which supports a format **and** a culture. Actually i don't understand the question at all since you're already using it but you're mentioning that you're using `String.Replace`.

Comment: because i got error when i used Replace code.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Currently am not using String.Replace because it throws different errors when i used that code..

Comment: So because you got an error with `Replace` you don't show us the code but instead you show code that should work without mentioning the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the C or c for formatting currencies:

```
string.Format("{0,C2}", value);
string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB"), "{0:C}", value)
```

Or with ToString and culture info:

```
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C2", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("da-DK"));
```

[Formating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

The usage of , or . is depending on the given culture you are formatting. You can give formatting rules for these.